# C++ - Object as a variable in parameters

Tags: c++, variables, object

I am learning C++ through TheNewBostons tutorials and there is one of the programs that I can't figure out how it works. I'll show you the codde before the question.

```
Main.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "People.h"
#include "Birthday.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Birthday birthObject(12,28,1986);

    People Ob("Vidar", birthObject);
    Ob.printInfo();
}
```

Birthday.h:

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H


class Birthday
{
    public:
        Birthday(int m,int d,int y);
        void prinDate();
    private:
        int month, day, year;
};

#endif
```

Birthday.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"

using namespace std;

Birthday::Birthday(int m,int d,int y)
{
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;
}

void Birthday::prinDate()
{
    cout << day << "/" << month << "-" << year << endl;
}
```

People.h:

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H

#include <string>
#include "Birthday.h"
using namespace std;

class People
{
    public:
        People(string x, Birthday bo);
        void printInfo();
    private:
        string name;
        Birthday dateOfBirth;
};

#endif
```

People.cpp:

```
#include "People.h"
#include "Birthday.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

People::People(string x, Birthday bo)
: name(x), dateOfBirth(bo)
{

}

void People::printInfo()
{
    cout << name << " was born on ";
    dateOfBirth.prinDate();
}
```

The thing that I can't figure out is how the objects are used as variables and parameters, and also how you can create an object without calling the constructor (in People.h).

Comment: what do you mean create an object without calling a constructor?

Comment: I think you rather want to pass your objects by reference than by value: `People(const string& x, const Birthday& bo);`. Also you need to have copy constructors and assignment operators defined for your classes.

Comment: your question is too vague...can you be a bit more specific??

Comment: His question is not vague, he doesn't understand implicit copy construction happening in `People::People`

Comment: Understanding copy constructors is a common problem for `C++` beginners. If you edit the question to be a more minimal example (one 10-line piece of code could demonstrate this), I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this step by step:

```
Birthday birthObject(12,28,1986);
```

here you're creating a new local variable `birthObject` of type of `Birthday` class, passing as parameters (12,289,1986). That invokes the three-parameter constructor of Birthday class

```
People Ob("Vidar", birthObject);
```

Here you're creating a local variable `Ob`of type `People` (note common conventions have class names starting with uppercase, variables starting with lowercase) and passing as parameters ("Vidar" and birthObject).

That invokes the two-parameters constructor of People. This is defined as:

```
People::People(string x, Birthday bo): name(x), dateOfBirth(bo) { }
```

Some notes here:

- Both parameters are passed by value. This means that the copy constructor (implicit, because you haven't defined any) will be invoked for each of them. (note, as it has been noted in other answers, it is probably best to use const & instead).
- attributes are initialized (name, dateOfBirth) (this involves an additional copy constructor for each of them).

  Ob.printInfo();

Finally, the printInfo() method of the Ob instance is invoked... which in turn invokes the prinData() method of the Ob's attribute dateOfBirth. Those methods do not have parameters and are invoked on the respective instances.

Answer (score 1):

This expression (mem initializer)

```
dateOfBirth(bo)
```

in the constructor definition

```
People::People(string x, Birthday bo)
: name(x), dateOfBirth(bo)
{

}
```

means a call of the copy constructor of class Birthday to construct object dateOfBirth from object bo.

For example if you would add an explicitly defined copy constructor for class Birthday the following way

```
class Birthday
{
    public:
        Birthday(int m,int d,int y);
        Birthday( const Birthday &rhs )
        {
            std::cout << "Birthday::Birthday( const Birthday & ) is called" << std::endl;
            month = rhs.month; day = rhs.day; year = rhs.year;
        } 
        void prinDate();
    private:
        int month, day, year;
};
```

then when this statement was executed

```
People Ob("Vidar", birthObject);
```

you would get message

```
Birthday::Birthday( const Birthday & ) is called
```

If you do not define explicitly the copy constructor then the compiler defines it implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable question.

What is happening here is that it is calling the copy constructor.

Whenever you declare a class there are several functions which are declared for you, unless you explicitly override them.

- Default constructor (if no other constructor is explicitly declared)
- Copy constructor if no move constructor or move assignment operator
  is explicitly declared. If a destructor is declared generation of a
  copy constructor is deprecated.
- Move constructor if no copy
  constructor, move assignment operator or destructor is explicitly
  declared.
- Copy assignment operator if no move constructor or move
  assignment operator is explicitly declared. If a destructor is
  declared generation of a copy assignment operator is deprecated.
- Move
  assignment operator if no copy constructor, copy assignment operator
  or destructor is explicitly declared.
- Destructor

Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions

In this case the copy constructor is called.